# Numpy.histogram with numpy.arange

Tags: python, json, numpy

I have a little problem using the numpy functions. I have a .json file with meteor data, that i have to arange by year. I have a list called yearlist, containing all the years with meteoer fallout.

I want to get a histogram showing the years where meteors have fallout in steps of 10 years.

I have tried this:

```
import json

from pprint import pprint
json_data = open('meteors.json')
data = json.load(json_data)
pprint(data[0])
json_data.close()

for count in range(0, 1180):
    yearlist = data[count]['year']
    print yearlist

import numpy
data = numpy.histogram(yearlist, bins=numpy.arange(1500, 2011, 10))
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: numpy.histogram just compute the histogram of a set of data, so if you want to get histogram visually, you should use matplotlib [hist](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist).

Comment: Beware that jumpy.histogram returns a tuple of the counts and bin edges. Do a bar plot of these and you are set.